# How to get the reactor from ApplicationRunner in autobahnPython

Tags: python, twisted, autobahn, crossbar

I have an autobahn client using the ApplicationRunner class from autobahn  to connect to a WAMP router (crossbar). In the main section it attaches my ApplicationSession class "REScheduler" like this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    from autobahn.twisted.wamp import ApplicationRunner

    runner = ApplicationRunner(url=u"ws://localhost:8080/ws", realm=u"RE_acct")

    runner.run(REScheduler, start_reactor=True, auto_reconnect=True)
```

Now I need the reactor that the application runner started for other purposes as well. Like e.g. to call some `reactor.callLater(...)`.
How can I access this reactor. I did not find anything in the docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twisted (sadly) uses a (process) global reactor object. That means, once a reactor is chosen (which `ApplicationRunner` does if you set `start_reactor=True`), simply do a `from twisted.internet import reactor` at **the place within your code** where you need it.

asyncio has properly encapsulated the event loop (you can have multiple event loops in a single process).

> txaio provides a convenience method that will work on both (it will expose the single, global reactor in Twisted, and it will expose the event loop under which ApplicationRunner is started): `txaio.config.loop = reactor`